# What are differents for Tab UI between BottomNavigationView and TabLayout in Android Studio 4.0?

Tags: android-studio

The Code A and Image A are from the project [architecture-components-samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples) .

The Code B and Image B are from the project [sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower).

The Code A use `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` to implement Tab UI.

The Code B use `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` to implement Tab UI.

It seems that the two controls can do the same things.

What are differents for Tab UI between BottomNavigationView and TabLayout in Android Studio 4.0?

**Code A**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Code B**

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sunflower.AppBarOverlay">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline5" />

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <!-- Override tabIconTint attribute of style with selector -->
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabIconTint="@drawable/tab_icon_color_selector"
                app:tabTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some subtle UX differences between the two, but here's a summary of when to use them from the [Material UI design guidelines](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#usage):

> Bottom navigation bars allow movement between primary destinations in an app
> ...
> Bottom navigation should be used for:
>
> - Top-level destinations that need to be accessible from anywhere in the app
> - Three to five destinations
> - Mobile or tablet only
>
> Bottom navigation shouldn’t be used for:
>
> - Single tasks, such as viewing a single email
> - User preferences or settings

Also note these guidelines:

[image]

You can read more about when to use [Tabs](https://material.io/components/tabs) vs [Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation) at the Material Design site.

Comment: Thanks!  Why can't  `Bottom navigation` use for "User preferences or settings" based your view?

Comment: Material design guidelines consider Settings to be a "secondary destination" that a user wouldn't need to interact with regularly. Bottom Navigation is supposed to just be for "primary destinations". However, these are all just guidelines. Your app will still work fine if your settings are accessible via the Bottom Navigation controls, it just won't be 100% adherent to Material Design guidelines.